# XAMPP opt/lmapp/lampp start script is doing nothing

Tags: 12.04, lamp, xampp

I installed Xampp for Ubuntu 12.04.  I was able to reach the Xampp splash page/index page.  Then, when I clicked on `myphpadmin`, it wasn't working and I would get an error page.

So instead I tried restarting my computer. After restart I assumed Apache had to be restarted. So, I went to `opt/lampp` and typed `lampp start`.  Nothing happens and I just get the directory and cursor again in my terminal.  Below is the snippet.

```
root@ubuntu:/opt/lampp# lampp start
lampp: command not found
root@ubuntu:/opt/lampp#
```

Anyone have any clues?

Thank you!

Comment: what is the output for `ls` in the directory,:)

Comment: how you have installed xampp ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is happen when you don't give the correct path for the script. You should start XAMPP using:

```
./lampp start
```

or

```
/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

If you are not logged as root, you can use:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

And if you [add your `/opt/lampp` directory to your PATH](https://askubuntu.com/q/60218/147044), after you can start it with:

```
sudo lampp start
```

Comment: Thank you very much. i needed the "./lampp start" to work. oh and btw phpmyadmin works now too.  I jumped for joy.

Thank you very much.  Now i'm off to gettin Drupal working.

Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how you have installed XAMPP in your Ubuntu , but I am giving the working way which I have tried personally in my Ubuntu PC.

just open your terminal and type as

```
wget http://www.apachefriends.org/download.php?xampp-linux-1.8.3-1-installer.run
chmod +x xampp-linux-1.8.3-1-installer.run
./xampp-linux-1.8.3-1-installer.run
```

after finishing the execution , just do as

```
sudo  /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this worked. the issue was that i was neglecting the './' infront of lampp.

Comment: @ZealotSveta glad to hear that. Enjoy Ubuntu. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Comment: Thank you this will work for me.